# How to return different values with the same method call in the same class in a loop?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am looping over a list table names to do the following

1. Call describe table to check if the table exists
2. If the table doesn't exist, throw ResourceNotFoundException.
3. Call createTable method to create the table
4. Call describe table to check if the table is created and is active.
5. If not active, wait.

After the tables have been successfully created I want to change some properties of the table too.

So now the issue I'm facing is with unit tests.

I need to do these two

```
when(ddbClient.describeTable)
    .thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    .thenReturn(mockTableDescription);
```

But this only throws the exception. Is it because I have a loop? How exactly am I supposed write this test?

Comment: If you throw ResourceNotFoundException, it would end up stopping the execution of method in your test altogether. Hence, all the steps after 2 will not even occur. Please share snippets of code being tested.